# Flutter Odoo : how to read all fields

Tags: flutter, odoo

iam making a flutter app that depending on odoo

and i want to get all fields in a module

so iam using read method

and iam depending on this library

http://oogbox.com/page/odoo-api-flutter.html

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/odoo_api/versions/1.0.1

the problem is that i tried everything to get all ids

i changed the List ids to []

and to null

and nothing working

and this is the code

```
final ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
final fields = ["id", "name", "email"];
client.read("res.partner", ids, fields).then((OdooResponse result) {
    if (!result.hasError()) {
        List records = result.getResult();
     } else {
        print (result.getError());
     }
});
```

Comment: From the documentation this read method doesnt allow you to bring all records, you should use searchRead() to do that. 

I think it should work passing the domain as a empty list as you have tried using read.

Comment: thank u .. it worked :) i think u need to put it in an answer to mark it as the right answer

Comment: Done, i'm glad it helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation this read method doesn't allow you to bring all records, you should use searchRead() and pass to the domain param an empty list to do that.